# Tub Faucet Handle goes back too far when turned off

Tags: faucet

My Delta roman tub faucet handle goes back too far when it is turned off. I tried to take the decorative base off (screws) and now that is stuck. I put WD40 in the thread area but it still won't move. So I have two questions:

1. how do I get the handle aligned correctly?
2. if the handle repairs requires me to take the base off, how can I get it unstuck?

I know that it screws off because I removed the one for the hot water easily

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are the pictures of the underside?  Normally you would just loosen of the nut or clamp screws on the bottom, rotate it to where you wish, and reaffix them.  If you messed with the base on the top side, you may need to disconnect it and uninstall it to get it un jammed.

Comment: You should also add a picture of the fasteners you tried to remove.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I attached a picture of the part that won't turn. It has such a small rim that I couldn't imagine a tool to be able to get a hold of it. The tub is completely tiles so no access to get to the plumbing underneath

Comment: You indicate that there's no access below. While this is _possible_, it's not likely. There's probably a removable panel somewhere to give access to the plumbing below. You may have to search a bit, as one wouldn't want it to be super obvious in a nicely decorated bathroom such as this, but I'm willing to bet that it's there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a plumber's wrench/plyer to hold the nut below the sink, and a helper to hold/adjust the handle into the correct position.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The tub is completely tiled so no access to get to the plumbing underneath

Comment: @Val Lynn Sorry, I messed up. Robber strap wrench might help then.

Comment: ok Thank. you so much! I will try that

Comment: Don't forget to loosen the screw first, if there is one.